# „Zahl der {etwas Negatives} rückläufig”. Gewachsen oder vermindert?

Tags: meaning-in-context, single-word-request

Auf der *taz* sah ich den folgenden Titel:

> Zahl der Hinrichtungen rückläufig ([taz.de](https://taz.de/Amnesty-zu-Todesstrafen-weltweit/!5498178/))

*Rückläufig* beschreibt beides:

1. die Entwicklung eines kleinerwerdenden Maßes

aber auch (in diesem Fall widersprüchlich):

2. zu einem früheren, schlechteren Zustand (d.h. mehr Hinrichtungen, in diesem Fall).

Ich las den Artikel, und habe festgestellt, dass es um Option 1. ging, wobei ich 2. erwartete.

Kann ein Muttersprachler kontextunabhängig --d.h. dessen bewusst, dass *Hinrichtung* (zumindest in der taz) eine eher negative Konnotation hat, aber ohne den Artikel zu lesen-- bestimmen, um welche Option es geht?

Das heißt, was hätte ich machen müssen, um den Titel richtig verstehen zu können?

Comment: Mir ist noch niemand untergekommen, der *rückläufig* als *so wie früher mal* verstanden hätte. Du bist der erste.

Comment: Als Muttersprachler habe ich Option 2) automatisch ausgeschlossen.

Ich denke, dass da ein Einschätzungsfaktor mit drin hängt, also was man in diesem Falle für möglich und nicht für möglich hält. 

Hätte man eventuell in den letzten Wochen in Newsfeeds nur über neue Hinrichtungen gelesen, dann denke ich, dass mehrere Leute die Bedeutung von rückläufig so wie du interpretiert hätten.

Comment: Hinrichtungen haben keine negative Konnotation. Es ist die Sache selbst, die Hinrichtung, die oft negativ gesehen wird - vom Henker vielleicht nicht und von Despoten und Falken nicht. Rückläufig wird wertfrei verwendet - eine Zahl ist rückläufig, d.h. sie nimmt ab. Ob das die Zahl der stark Übergewichtigen ist oder die Zahl der Normalgewichtigen. Die Zahl der Marzipaneier in Supermärkten ist auch gerade extrem rückläufig.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Duden nennt für *rückläufig* tatsächlich zwei Bedeutungen:

1. *eine rückläufige [Preis]entwicklung* - Damit eine Zahl, die sich vermindert (das wäre wahrscheinlich die Bedeutung, auf die 95% der Muttersprachler sofort kommen würden)
2. *in Richtung des Ausgangspunktes verlaufend, führend* - Das ist deine zweite vermutete Bedeutung, die sich aber immer auf eine **Bewegung** beziehen muß

Wie man sieht, unterscheiden sich die Bedeutungen genau dann, wenn von einer *Zahl* oder einer *Bewegung* die Rede ist. Die positive oder negative Konotation des Dings, um das es geht, hat damit überhaupt nichts zu tun. In deinem Beispiel wird eindeutig eine Zahl genannt, damit kann es sich nur um die erste Bedeutung handeln. Bei "rückläufigen Hinrichtungen" im Sinne von "rückgängig gemachten Hinrichtungen" würden mir Dinge wie wieder angesetzte Köpfe einfallen...

Answer (score 7):

Nun ja, das Subjekt ist ja "die Zahl". Diese ist rückläufig. Hierbei ist es irrelevant, welche Zahl und ob das Objekt nun positiv oder negativ konnotiert ist.

Du kannst sowohl sagen:

> Die Zahl der Hinrichtungen ist rückläufig.

oder

> Die Zahl der Geburten ist rückläufig.

Immer ist klar: Irgendetwas wird weniger. Im genannten Fall die Zahl der Hinrichtungen. Insgesamt ist dies eine positive Entwicklung.

Wenn nämlich die Anzahl negativer Dinge zurückgeht, ist dies in der Gesamtheit eine positive Entwicklung.

Ich persönlich verstehe *rückläufig sein* eigentlich nie als Entwicklung zu einem früheren, schlechteren Zustand hin und wüsste nicht, dass es wirklich so gebraucht würde. Ich kenne nur die Bedeutung, dass eine gegebene Größe sich verringert.

Answer (score 6):

Ja, Leute mit Deutsch als Hauptsozialisationssprache haben kein Problem, hier die intendierte Bedeutung

> Zahl der Hinrichtungen geht zurück

zu erfassen. Im Gegenteil, deine zweite Deutungsmöglichkeit wirkt sehr unnatürlich oder konstruiert. Ich selbst habe "rückläufig" in einem solchen Sinne (rückwärtsgewandt? reaktionär?) noch nie irgendwo angetroffen. (Wo hast du denn diese Zweitbedeutung her?)

Wenn Statistisches beschrieben wird, auch in journalistischen Texten, wird "rückläufig" zur Angabe eines Trends bei Quantitäten sehr häufig verwendet.

Comment: "Im Gegenteil, deine zweite Deutungsmöglichkeit wirkt sehr unnatürlich oder konstruiert." - wieso? "rückläufig = läuft zu einem früheren Zustand zurück" ist doch eigentlich ganz logisch und naheliegend, zumal das ähnlich klingende "rückfällig" eine ähnliche Bedeutung hat.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Seit wann ist denn Sprache *logisch und naheliegend*? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Die Zahl der Hinrichtungen geht nicht zurück, zu einem früheren Wert. Sondern im Sinne wie etwa "rückwärtsgehen" geht die Zahl zurück im Sinne von weg, nicht aber im Sinne von schlechter.
Hier ist das Deutsche nicht eindeutig.